# How do you make a post request via Fetch in Nativescript?

Tags: express, post, request, fetch, nativescript

I have a server.js file. With a post request (/login). It looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql')
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))


app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log("login")
    console.log(req);
})
```

I also have a function in NativeScript that is supposed to make a post request (where the fetch is) when a button is pressed. It looks like this:

```
export function onLoginButtonTap() {
    console.log("login button tapped")
    const frame = Frame.getFrameById("mainFrame");

    // TODO: user authentication
    var userEmail = `${bindingContext.get('email')}`;
    var userPassword = `${bindingContext.get('password')}`;

    // make sure fields are filled out
    if (userPassword === "" || userEmail === "") {
        alert({
            title: "Login Error",
            message: "One or more fields is empty. Please fill in every field.",
            okButtonText: "OK",
        })
    } else {
        // TODO: post request (send user input to backend for verification)
        console.log("here1")
        const data = {userEmail, userPassword};
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", options);
    
        // if user is in database change page to home
        frame.navigate("pages/home/home-page");
    }

    // navigates to home page without requiring login info (for testing)
    frame.navigate("pages/home/home-page");
}
```

The post request doesn't work. I would like the console.logs in the server file to print the request. I think the problem is how I wrote the post request? Currently nothing happens.

Comment: BTW, the frontend and backend are in completely separate directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch return a promise, you need to resolve it to actually make the `POST` request. Try the following block of code.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/login', options)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((result) => {
            console.log('Success:', result);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
          });
```

Comment: I tried that and got this output "Error: TypeError: Network request failed".

Comment: I just realized something... It's "localhost"... I've been doing the testing on my phone... Wow... It should work with an emulator though. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Maybe try to run it on your same machine first, isolate problem into smaller unit and solve them 1 by 1

Comment: Okay, so what I did was launch the express server on Heroku with a worker dyno (not web), and what I did was change the fetch to "fetch('https:/myprojectname/herokuapp.com/login'), and it prints the 'Error: ' + error part. The error is "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0". It's not parsing the JSON correctly I'm assuming?

Comment: Yeap, that's the common error for invalid JSON.

Comment: Get requests work. For example, if I have https://myprojectname/herokuapp.com/test it will print anything I have in the server file under that request (for example, res.json("test") will display "test"). The problem has to be something with the fetch on the frontend, and unfortunately that's not where I'm not an expert. I'm used to doing it through forms in HTML not fetch in js.